# Laravel e Json Web Token

Tags: php, html, json, laravel

Estou com dificuldade em fazer a autenticação através do token do Json Web Token (JWT) no framework Laravel, estou utilizando o framework há pouco tempo e me deparei com o seguinte erro.

```
    Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

1/1
ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 112:
Undefined index: password
in EloquentUserProvider.php line 112
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: password', 'D:\web\XAMPP\htdocs\SIAPE\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php', '112', array('user' => object(User), 'credentials' => array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER'))) in EloquentUserProvider.php line 112
at EloquentUserProvider->validateCredentials(object(User), array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in Guard.php line 390
at Guard->hasValidCredentials(object(User), array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in Guard.php line 370
at Guard->attempt(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER'), false, false) in Guard.php line 275
at Guard->validate(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in Guard.php line 258
at Guard->once(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER'))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Guard), 'once'), array(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER'))) in Manager.php line 137
at Manager->__call('once', array(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER'))) in IlluminateAuthAdapter.php line 31
at AuthManager->once(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in IlluminateAuthAdapter.php line 31
at IlluminateAuthAdapter->byCredentials(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in JWTAuth.php line 99
at JWTAuth->attempt(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in Facade.php line 216
at Facade::__callStatic('attempt', array(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER'))) in AuthenticateController.php line 29
at JWTAuth::attempt(array('A901_codusu' => '1', 'A901_login' => 'MASTER')) in AuthenticateController.php line 29
at AuthenticateController->authenticate(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AuthenticateController), 'authenticate'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('authenticate', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(AuthenticateController), object(Route), 'authenticate') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(AuthenticateController), object(Route), object(Request), 'authenticate') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'SIAPE\Http\Controllers\AuthenticateController', 'authenticate') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 712
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 714
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 679
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 639
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
at require_once('D:\web\XAMPP\htdocs\SIAPE\public\index.php') in index.php line 21
```

Eis que eu estava seguindo este tutorial [Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps) , todos os passos, exceto os referentes à tabela de usuários, a qual ele utiliza a do próprio framework. Eu tenho minha própria tabela de usuários, sendo assim não tenho interesse em utilizar à do laravel. Este erro me aparece porque eu não tenho um campo password no meu banco de dados, já alterei os arquivos app.php, jwt.php no que se refere a tabela User mas parece que o framework exige que minha tabela tenha um campo com este nome "password" para autenticação. meu controler está assim:

```
<?php

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        // TODO: show users
    }    

    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        // grab credentials from the request
        $credentials = $request->only('A901_codusu', 'A901_login');

        try {
            // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
            if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        // all good so return the token
        return response()->json(compact('token'));
    }


    public function getAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        try {

            if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
            }

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

        }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim
        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }
}
```

Preciso encontrar uma forma de o Laravel reconhecer minha tabela ("T901_Usuarios") e não exigir que eu tenha um campo "password" para fazer a autenticação.

Comment: Seu problema não é especificamente na tabela. Uma autenticação JWT requer email e senha e você provavelmente não está fornecendo esses dados.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma solução simples, basta sobreesrever o método que busca a senha de autenticação do láravel.

```
public function getAuthPassword(){
  return md5($this->A901_senha);
}
```

e retornar o campo de senha que você quer utilizar na sua autenticação.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer um *overwrite* no método **getCredentials**()

```
/**
 * Get the needed authorization credentials from the request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
{
    return $request->only( 'field_email', 'field_passwd' );
}
```